# Apache poi sheet password not working

Tags: java, excel

I've got my excel file sheet locking as

```
XSSFSheet resultSheet = ((XSSFSheet) getResultSheet(workbook));
resultSheet.getCTWorksheet().getSheetProtection().setPassword(PASSWORD.getBytes());
resultSheet.lockSelectUnlockedCells(false);
resultSheet.lockSelectLockedCells(true);
resultSheet.lockFormatCells(true);
resultSheet.lockFormatColumns(true);
resultSheet.lockFormatRows(true);
resultSheet.lockInsertColumns(true);
resultSheet.lockInsertRows(true);
resultSheet.lockInsertHyperlinks(true);
resultSheet.lockDeleteColumns(true);
resultSheet.lockDeleteRows(true);
resultSheet.lockSort(true);
resultSheet.lockAutoFilter(true);
resultSheet.lockPivotTables(true);
resultSheet.lockObjects(true);
resultSheet.lockScenarios(true);
resultSheet.enableLocking();
```

This code sample protects sheet, but lets it be unlocked without password. I've also tried `CTSheetProtection ctSheetProtection = CTSheetProtection.Factory.newInstance();`
but unsuccessful.
Apache poi version is

```
compile ('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.15') {
    exclude module: 'poi-ooxml-schemas'
}
compile 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.3'
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultSheet.setSheetPassword(PASSWORD, HashAlgorithm.md5);
```

Comment: I'm using POI 3.17 and this is not working: sheet can be unlocked without a password prompt...